# How to run single test method with phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am struggling to run a single test method named `testSaveAndDrop` in the file `escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php` with `phpunit`. I tried the following combinations:

```
phpunit EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php --filter=escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php::testSaveAndDrop
phpunit EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php --filter=EscalationGroupTest.php::testSaveAndDrop
phpunit EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php --filter=EscalationGroupTest::testSaveAndDrop
phpunit EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php --filter=testSaveAndDrop
```

In each case *all* test methode in the file `escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php` are executed. How to select just ONE method instead?

The name of the class is `EscalationGroupTest` and the version of `phpunit` is 3.2.8.

Comment: What is the class name of your test class?

Answer (score 673, accepted):

The following command runs the test on a single method:

```
phpunit --filter testSaveAndDrop EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php

phpunit --filter methodName ClassName path/to/file.php
```

For newer versions of phpunit, it is just:

```
phpunit --filter methodName path/to/file.php
```

Comment: Did writting EscalationGroupTest  is required? What is the use of it?

Comment: Ok I got it is the class name

Comment: It will run test method with name testSaveAndDrop* ( example: testSaveAndDropSomething) too. To run exactly testSaveAndDrop use --filter '/::testSaveAndDrop$/'

Comment: .php extension is also unnecessary

Comment: @mujaffars I doubt it, "I got it" is not a valid identifier in php due to the whitespace.

Comment: This doesn't work now. It's just `phpunit --filter methodName path/to/testing/file`, no `ClassName `.

Comment: @FaridMovsumov you should make that an answer with explanation ;) btw usually simpler enforcing regex `--filter="/testApply$/"` works for me

Comment: Even more recently, phpunit -v 8.5.19, you only need to specify `phpunit --filter ClassName::MethodName`

Comment: This will specify the testing file, the specific test, and prevent similarly named tests from running such as "it_can_do_something_else".
`php artisan test --filter SomeControllerTest::it_can_do_something$`

Answer (score 287):

I prefer marking the test in annotation as

```
/**
 * @group failing
 * Tests the api edit form
 */
public function testEditAction()
```

Then running it with

```
phpunit --group failing
```

No need to specify the full path in the command line, but you have to remember removing this before commit, not to clutter the code.

You may also specify several groups for a single test

```
/**
  * @group failing
  * @group bug2204 
  */
public function testSomethingElse()
{
}
```

Comment: I like this method, is it possible to assign multiple groups via the annotation?
`@group failing, Integration`

Comment: Yes, of course. But not comma separated. Edited the answer to illustrate this.

Comment: I like this method better... for reference the <groups> element in phpunit.xml can also be used to filter the tests... use something like this right under ````<phpunit>````: 

    <groups><include><group>failing</group></include></groups>

Comment: But the question was - to run SINGLE test. Also - group named failing is the worst you can use. Because after some tests fail you can run phpunit --group failing to run the failed tests without giving them the group. It's confusing.

Comment: The best answer! there is NO SINGLE test in case it `@depends` from another so you have to pinpoint all interconnected tests and thus use the `@group` annotation.

Comment: this should be preferred answere

Answer (score 137):

Here's the more generic answer:

If you are sure the method name is unique you can only filter by method name *(this works for me)*

```
phpunit --filter {TestMethodName}
```

However it is safer to specify the file path/reference as well

```
phpunit --filter {TestMethodName} {FilePath}
```

Example:

```
phpunit --filter testSaveAndDrop reference/to/escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php
```

Quick note: I've noticed that if I have a function named `testSave` and another function named `testSaveAndDrop` using command `phpunit --filter testSave` will also run `testSaveAndDrop` and any other function that starts with `testSave*`, it's weird!!

Comment: It's not weird at all, it is basically a substring match. If you want that behaviour, use end of string token: `/testSave$/`

Comment: What if you only want to specify the file path so all tests in that file get run?

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Just don't add --filter {TestMethodName} and give only the path.

Answer (score 60):

Following command will execute **exactly** `testSaveAndDrop` test.

```
phpunit --filter '/::testSaveAndDrop$/' escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Using `\b` instead of `$` finally did the trick: `--filter '/::testSaveAndDrop\b/'`.

Comment: Both of the method name endings `'/::testSaveAndDrop\b/'` and `'/::testSaveAndDrop$/'` worked for me like this `phpunit --filter ClassName::methodName$` and `phpunit --filter ClassName::methodName\b` (on Linux)

Comment: Same here: both work (on Linux), plus the `/` characters are optional (PHPUnit 9.5.13).

Comment: @Joe Just a hunch: do you have `()` after your method names in the PhpDoc comments? That may be why `$` didn't work, and why `\b` works for both.

Answer (score 58):

- **Run this inside your project root directory i am using in laravel root directory.**

---

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Your method name'
```

**Example with custom method name.**

```
 /** @test //Initilize this for custom method name, without test keyword
  *  
  * Test case For Dashboard When User Not logged In it will redirect To login page
  */
  public function only_logged_in_user_see_dashboard()
  {
    $response = $this->get('/dashboard')
                   ->assertRedirect('/login');
  }
```

**Example with test keyword**

```
/**
* A basic test example.
*
* @return void
*/
 public function testBasicTest()
 {
  $this->assertTrue(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 47):

for run phpunit test in laravel by many way ..

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter methodName className pathTofile.php

vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'namespace\\directoryName\\className::methodName'
```

for test single class :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter  tests/Feature/UserTest.php
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature\\UserTest'
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'UserTest'
```

for test single method :

```
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testExample 
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature\\UserTest::testExample'
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testExample UserTest tests/Feature/UserTest.php
```

for run tests from all class within namespace  :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature'
```

for more way run test [see more](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/textui.html#textui-examples-testcaseclass-php)

Answer (score 30):

So, something like this

```
phpunit --filter 'EscalationGroupTest::testSaveAndDrop' EscalationGroupTest escalation/EscalationGroupTest.php
```

Without `=` and with `'`

https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html

Comment: No this does not work. All tests in the class `EscalationGroupTest` are being processed.

Comment: Still all 9 tests are being run. phpunit version 3.2.8

Comment: Move the `--filter` to before the filename and things should work right.

Comment: Worked for me on PHPUnit 4.8.10

Comment: This gives me `No tests executed!` on PHPUnit `4.8.35`

@Schleis How exactly did you change the command?

Answer (score 10):

Given that you

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter=EscalationGroupTest::testSaveAndDrop
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're in netbeans you can right click in the test method and click "Run Focused Test Method".

[image: Run Focused Test Method menu]

Answer (score 7):

You Can try this i am able to run single Test cases

```
phpunit tests/{testfilename}
```

Eg:

```
phpunit tests/StackoverflowTest.php
```

If you want to run single Test cases in Laravel 5.5 Try

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/{testfilename} 

vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/{testfilename}
```

Eg:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/ContactpageTest.php 

vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/ContactpageTest.php
```

Comment: The question was how to run single test METHOD (not class)

Answer (score 5):

The reason your tests are all being run is that you have the `--filter` flag after the file name.  PHPUnit is not reading the options at all and so is running all the test cases.

From the help screen:

```
 Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
        phpunit [options] <directory>
```

So move the `--filter` argument before the test file that you want as mentioned in @Alex and 
@Ferid Mövsümov answers.  And you should only have the test that you want run.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the original question...I had the same problem of needing to run just one of the tests in a file containing many unit tests, and the two other answers using filters worked for me

Comment: @jfoo One of the problems with the OP's commands was that the `--filter` option was after the file name.  The other two answers had the correct answer but did not point out why the filter was being applied.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an XML configuration file, you can add the following inside the `phpunit` tag:

```
<groups>
  <include>
    <group>nameToInclude</group>
  </include>
  <exclude>
    <group>nameToExclude</group>
  </exclude>
</groups>
```

See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party though. But as personal I hate to write the whole line.

Instead, I use the following shortcuts in the **.bash_profile** file make sure to **source .bash_profile** the file after adding any new alias else it won't work.

```
alias pa="php artisan"
alias pu="vendor/bin/phpunit" 
alias puf="vendor/bin/phpunit --filter"
```

Usage:

```
puf function_name

puf filename
```

If you use **Visual Studio Code** you can use the following package to make your tests breeze.

```
Package Name: Better PHPUnit
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=calebporzio.better-phpunit
```

You can then set the keybinding in the settings. I use **Command + T** binding in my MAC.

Now once you place your cursor on any **function** and then use the key binding then it will automatically run that single test.

If you need to run the whole **class** then place the cursor on top of the class and then use the key binding.

If you have any other things then always tweek with the **Terminal**

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You must use --filter to run a single test method
`php phpunit --filter "/::testMethod( .*)?$/" ClassTest ClassTest.php`

The above filter will run testMethod alone.