# Get "Run Focused Test Method" to work in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

A file, SearchTest.php, has:

```
public function testSearchThenBooking(){
...
}
```

When I right-click I can see "Run Focused Test Method" (and "Debug Focused Test Method"), but they are greyed out.

I realized the phpunit netbeans plugin was not installed. So I've installed that, restarted netbeans, but no difference.

phpunit from the commandline is working fine, and running and passing this function.

This answer show it is obviously working for some people! https://stackoverflow.com/a/30568731/841830

Do I need to configure my project to use phpunit, or tell it where phpunit is, or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to manually download [PHPUnit Script](https://phpunit.de/) and [Skeleton Generator Script](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator)

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-skelgen.phar
chmod +x phpunit-skelgen.phar
sudo mv phpunit-skelgen.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit-skelgen
```

and complete the Tools/Options/Frameworks & Tools form

[image]

Full details for installation and configuration can be found [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html). But even if you do that, it won't work because there is a bug in the last version of netbeans (8.0.2).

[Bug 254276 - NetBeans v8.0.2 incompatible w/ latest PHPUnit version.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254276)

So you have two choices: either you use a [nightly build](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/) that will contain the following [patch](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/rev/4bac9677cf11) solving the problem:

```
 1.1 --- a/php.phpunit/src/org/netbeans/modules/php/phpunit/commands/PhpUnit.java
 1.2 +++ b/php.phpunit/src/org/netbeans/modules/php/phpunit/commands/PhpUnit.java
 1.3 @@ -123,6 +123,7 @@
 1.4      private static final String COVERAGE_LOG_PARAM = "--coverage-clover"; // NOI18N
 1.5      private static final String LIST_GROUPS_PARAM = "--list-groups"; // NOI18N
 1.6      private static final String GROUP_PARAM = "--group"; // NOI18N
 1.7 +    private static final String PARAM_SEPARATOR = "--"; // NOI18N
 1.8      // bootstrap & config
 1.9      private static final String BOOTSTRAP_PARAM = "--bootstrap"; // NOI18N
1.10      private static final String BOOTSTRAP_FILENAME = "bootstrap%s.php"; // NOI18N
1.11 @@ -319,6 +320,8 @@
1.12              // #218607 - hotfix
1.13              //params.add(SUITE_NAME)
1.14              params.add(getNbSuite().getAbsolutePath());
1.15 +            // #254276
1.16 +            params.add(PARAM_SEPARATOR);
1.17              params.add(String.format(SUITE_RUN, joinPaths(runInfo.getStartFiles(), SUITE_PATH_DELIMITER)));
1.18          }
1.19
```

either you wait for the next release.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try again when the next version, with the bug fix,  is released. (I have phpunit path set, but not the skeleton generator.)