# How to execute specific test class using PHPUnit in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I want to test specific testClass in my project since there are a lot of test class that's failure and I just want to test one Class at a time.

I've created the test Class in following folder `\test\repositories\ApplicationVersionFormat.php`  :

```
<?php
use App\Repositories\ApplicationVersionFormat;

class ApplicationVersionFormatTest extends \TestCase
{
  public function testValidFormat()
  {
    $version = '1.2.3';
    $appVersion = new ApplicationVersionFormat();
    $this->assertEquals(true,$appVersion->isValidVersion($version));
  }

  public function testInvalidFormat()
  {
    $version = '11.2.3';
    $appVersion = new ApplicationVersionFormat();
    $this->assertEquals(false,$appVersion->isValidVersion($version));
  }

  public function testInvalidFormat2()
  {
    $version = '1.22.3';
    $appVersion = new ApplicationVersionFormat();
    $this->assertEquals(false,$appVersion->isValidVersion($version));
  }

  public function testInvalidFormat3()
  {
    $version = '1.2.33';
    $appVersion = new ApplicationVersionFormat();
    $this->assertEquals(false,$appVersion->isValidVersion($version));
  }

  public function testInvalidFormat4()
  {
    $version = '11.22.33';
    $appVersion = new ApplicationVersionFormat();
    $this->assertEquals(false,$appVersion->isValidVersion($version));
  }
}
```

so I've tried this follwing command but none of this works :

- `phpunit "repositories\AppVersionTest"`. => **Cannot open file "test/repositories/AppVersionTest.php"**
- `phpunit "test\repositories\AppVersionTest"`. => **Cannot open file "test/repositories/AppVersionTest.php"**
- `phpunit --filter "repositories\AppVersionTest"`. => **No tests executed!**
- `phpunit --testsuite "repositories\AppVersionTest"`.  => **No tests executed!**

Comment: what's the output of the command you execute?

Comment: Try checking to some inclusion/exclusion configuration in your phpunit.xml(.dist) files. Can you post this files?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

After trying several ways, I found out that I don't need to include the folder to test the specific test class. This works for me it runs all the test on the class:

`phpunit --filter ApplicationVersionFormatTest`

I think it's because my ApplicationVersionFormatTest extend The TestCase and return application instance which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel.

Comment: In addition to the phpunit command, you may use the test Artisan command to run your tests. The Artisan test runner provides verbose test reports in order to ease development and debugging:

Comment: I've tried to put the whole test namespace, but it didn't work; you should pass the class name only for it to work.

Comment: You last voted on this answer May 26, 2021 at 13:51. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited. here we come again :) after 2 years

Answer (score 125):

for run phpunit test in laravel by many ways ..

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter methodName className pathTofile.php

vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'namespace\\directoryName\\className::methodName'
```

for test single class:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/UserTest.php
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter  tests/Feature/UserTest.php
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature\\UserTest'
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'UserTest'
```

for test single method:

```
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testExample 
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature\\UserTest::testExample'
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testExample UserTest tests/Feature/UserTest.php
```

for run tests from all class within namespace:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter 'Tests\\Feature'
```

for more way run test [see more](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/textui.html#textui-examples-testcaseclass-php)

Comment: `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter  tests/Feature/UserTest.php` returns to test excuted in my case.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/UserTest.php`, finally in the end from all the others this one worked for me. Because I strictly wanted to test single file, with filter it goes into fuzzy search and then tests also similar tests that contained the Deal name in the above case, but your solution there was fool proofed. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 93):

To do the same thing using `artisan` run:

```
php artisan test --filter ApplicationVersionFormatTest
```

Comment: In my case it works with the default Feature and Unit folders, but if i create a new testsuite, it does not work .

Comment: @Berni make sure your newly added test class ends with Test, else PHPUnit will not recognize it.

Comment: @Berni be sure to add the new test suite to your phpunit.xml file.

Answer (score 30):

For newer version this might work

```
php artisan test --filter {MethodName}

// for instance
php artisan test --filter test_example
```

OR

```
php artisan test --filter {ClassName}::{MethodName}

//for instance
php artisan test --filter ExampleTest::test_example
```

Comment: What about filtering by directory?

Answer (score 11):

You can probably manage that with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28695208/4725998) to a related question.

Just mark the class with `@group` annotation and run PHPUnit with `--group <group_name>`

**Update**

Your command with `--filter` is not complete. Try this: `phpunit --filter AppVersionTest "repositories\ApplicationVersionFormat.php"`

Answer (score 4):

For laravel 8

```
php artisan test --filter ExampleTest
```

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 10

For specific test class:

```
php artisan test --filter UserTest
```

for a specific method test of UserTest:

```
php artisan test --filter UserTest::test_create_user
```

Answer (score 1):

`phpunit --filter <relative_path_to_file>`
for example , files to test are,`test/repos/EloquentPushTest.php`,`test/repos/EloquentWebTest.php`
for testing `EloquentWebTest.php`

use `phpunit --filter ./repos/ElqouentWebpush`

Answer (score 0):

Example of use:

```
php phpunit-5.7.27.phar -c app/ "src/package/TestBundle/Tests/Controller/ExampleControllerTest.php"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using **phpunit.xml**

the `@group` option can be used on classes and methods.

class A

```
/**
 * @group active
 * */
class ArrayShiftRightTest extends TestCase
{
}
```

class B

```
/**
 * @group inactive
 * */
class BinaryGapTest extends TestCase
{    
}
```

in `phpunit.xml`

```
<groups>
    <include>
        <group>active</group>
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <group>inactive</group>
    </exclude>
</groups>
```

the classes that belongs to group active will be executed.