# How to run phpunit in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, windows, laravel-5.5

I have a problem running phpunit in my laravel 5.5. I already go to vendor/bin and then execute phpunit using my command prompt in windows. But cmd just give another option or flag as shown in the picture below :
[image]

I have read laravel 5.5 documentation for unittest. It's said that we just need to execute phpunit {as shown in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/testing}
Then I tried this :
[How to run single test method with phpunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095051/how-to-run-single-test-method-with-phpunit)

```
phpunit --filter testBasicTest tests\Unit\ExampleTest
```

As shown below :
[image]

BUt it's said that 'cannot open the file'. Then I Tried 
phpunit ExampleTest, but still cannot open the file. So what's wrong here...?
Thanks in advance

Note :
Here's my phpunit.xml :
[image]

Answer (score 25):

You need to run phpunit without getting inside the bin folder.

Try this:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This will load your `phpunit.xml` file. Otherwise it cannot load your configuration file. Unless if you don't give spesific path:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /path/to/laravels/phpunit.xml
```

Comment: I tried cd vendor/bin && phpunit but it still gives me the same result as above....

Comment: what about configuration?

Comment: there are so many phpunit.xml files located in different project folders, don't know which one is used for configuration

Comment: Also can be useful if you will use the Cygwin instead of default windows console

Answer (score 1):

Just install **phpunit** through composer:

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

then all you are set to test your laravel project.