# VIM: How to get the current function name

Tags: vim, vi

In my vim configuration, I mapped `,pt` to run a phpunit test.

```
map <leader>pt :!clear && vendor/bin/phpunit % --testdox<cr>
```

But sometimes I want to run a specific test by using phpunit [--filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095567/959060)

```
map <leader>pt :!clear && vendor/bin/phpunit --filter {FUNCTION_NAME_HERE} % --testdox<cr>
```

Is there anyway we can fill the function name automatically in vim?

Comment: Let me try it @phd

Comment: @phd, I'm sorry but I can't make it work. I've updated my .vimrc with `map <leader>pg :!clear && vendor/bin/phpunit --filter expand('<sfile>') % --testdox<cr>`, tested it, and the result is `E498: no :source file name to substitute for "<sfile>"`

Comment: `<sfile>` is for VimScript only. I guess you need `shellescape(matchstr(getline(search('function', 'bcnW')), 'function\s\+\zs\w\+'))` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I'm sorry but didn't worked too... `map <leader>pg :!clear && vendor/bin/phpunit --filter shellescape(matchstr(getline(search('function', 'bcnW')), 'function\s\+\zs\w\+')) % --testdox<cr>`

Comment: Surely, it does not, as the whole VimScript statement gets transferred literally to the shell, which knows nothing about VimScript. I'd be very amused if that worked. Read `:h :execute` for a starter.

Answer (score 1):

As a *text editor*, Vim only has a limited understanding of the structure of the underlying source code.

Potential sources for the current method name could be:

- the jump to the previous start of a method: [`:help [m`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5Bm)
- syntax highlighting
- the [tags](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags) database; plugins like [taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) and [tagbar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) highlight the current definition automatically

Alternatively, you could attempt to resolve the function name via pattern extraction (as @Matt has suggested in the comments; via something like `matchstr(getline(search('function', 'bcnW')), 'function\s\+\zs\w\+')`) - but this would be limited to the current language and hard to get correct 100% of the time.

In summary, this is not straightforward and would involve advanced Vimscript to do right.

#### Alternative

Instead of a mapping that automates this fully, I would go for the 80% solution, a custom [`:command`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand) that you can pass the function name:

```
command -nargs=1 Phpunit !clear && vendor/bin/phpunit --filter <args> % --testdox
```

Like the mapping, it will still save considerable typing. You can *yank* the function name to paste it in, or if the cursor currently is on top of it, just insert it into the `:Phpunit` command-line via [`<C-R><C-W>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W).

As a next step, you could make `:Phpunit` handle zero arguments and then drop the `--filter` argument, so your mapping would become `:nnoremap <Leader>pt :Phpunit<CR>`